# Is org.exolab.castor.xml.schema.Schema thread safe?

Tags: java, castor

Is Castor's [Schema](http://www.castor.org/javadoc/org/exolab/castor/xml/schema/Schema.html) object thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

The first guess is yes. Becuase [in its source it](http://docjar.com/html/api/org/exolab/castor/xml/schema/Schema.java.html) has many syncronised methods and also it mostly uses Hashtable (which is thread-safe) to store its internal data. So, I would guess that people that designed that class thought about thread-safeness and if it's not thread-safe for some reason, then it's most likely a bug.